# NameError: global name 'imshow' is not defined but Matplotlib is imported

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, terminal, imshow

I'm currently writing a python script which plots a numpy matrix containing some data (which I'm not having any difficulty computing). For complicated reasons having to do with how I'm creating that data, I have to go through terminal. I've done problems like this a million times in Spyder using `imshow()`. So, I thought I'd try to do the same in terminal. Here's my code:

```
      from numpy import *
      from matplotlib import *

      def make_picture():
          f = open("DATA2.txt")
          arr = zeros((200, 200))
          l = f.readlines()
          for i in l:
              j = i[:-1]
              k = j.split(" ")
              arr[int(k[0])][int(k[1])] = float(k[2])
          f.close()
          imshow(arr)

      make_picture()
```

Suffice it to say, the array stuff works just fine. I've tested it, and it extracts the data perfectly well. So, I've got this 200 by 200 array of numbers floating around my RAM and I'd like to display it. When I run this code in Spyder, I get exactly what I expected. However, when I run this code in Terminal, I get an error message:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "DATAmine.py", line 15, in <module>
          make_picture()
        File "DATAmine.py", line 13, in make_picture
          imshow(arr)
      NameError: global name 'imshow' is not defined
```

(My program's called DATAmine.py) What's the deal here? Is there something else I should be importing? I know I had to configure my Spyder paths, so I wonder if I don't have access to those paths or something. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. Perhaps I should mention I'm using Ubuntu. Don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: You probably need `from matplotlib.pyplot import *` to fix your immediate issue. Probably when `imshow` has worked in the past, you've been using Spyder in pylab mode, which automatically imports a lot of this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your life easier you can use

```
from pylab import *
```

This will import the full pylab package, which includes matplotlib and numpy.

Cheers